# Chatbot delay between saying something and getting answer

Tags: java, delay

So in my chatbot program, I want to make it so it waits about 2 seconds after I said something before it answers. I tried the sleep method but that makes what I said be delayed as well...
I tried to find something on the wait method but I can't seem to find out how it works so here's my piece of code for answering.
I want it to wait 2 seconds after doing the "addText(ft.format(dNow) + " |-->You:\t"+quote);" part and then write the answer of the chatbot

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
                      Date dNow = new Date( );
                      SimpleDateFormat ft = 
                      new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss");

            input.setEditable(false);
            //-----grab quote-----------
            String quote=input.getText();
            input.setText("");
            addText(ft.format(dNow) + " |-->You:\t"+quote);

            quote.trim();
            while(
                quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='!' ||
                quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='.' ||
                quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='?'
            )
            {
                quote=quote.substring(0,quote.length()-1);
            }
            quote=quote.trim();
            byte response=0;

            //-----check for matches----
            int j=0;//which group we're checking
            while(response==0){
                if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),chatBot[j*2]))
                {
                    response=2;
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*chatBot[(j*2)+1].length);
                    addText("\n" + ft.format(dNow) + " |-->Miku\t"+chatBot[(j*2)+1][r]);
                    if(j*2==0){
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mikuname.txt"))) {
                        String name;
                        while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        addText(name +"!");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // Do something with the IO problem that occurred while reading the file
                    }
                }
                }
                j++;
                if(j*2==chatBot.length-1 && response==0)
                {
                    response=1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` would only work if you had the response processed on a different thread. Because you don't, you'll need to take a different approach.

Use the `ScheduledExecutorService` object to schedule a task for two seconds in the future.

**Example**

```
// Create the service object.
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
// Schedule the task for the next 5 seconds.
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Executed!");
        return "Called!";
    }
},
5,
TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

*Code taken from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could schedule whatever you want to send out using a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Here's an [example](http://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-and-timertask-example-tutorial)